# R - How to extract slope and intercept from lm.fit?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I need a faster way of doing linear regression than the lm() method. I found that lm.fit() is quite a bit faster but I'm wondering how to use the results. For example using this code:

```
x = 1:5
y = 5:1

regr = lm.fit(as.matrix(x), y)
str(regr)
```

Outputs:

```
List of 8
 $ coefficients : Named num 0.636
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "x1"
 $ residuals    : num [1:5] 4.364 2.727 1.091 -0.545 -2.182
 $ effects      : Named num [1:5] -4.719 1.69 -0.465 -2.619 -4.774
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "x1" "" "" "" ...
 $ rank         : int 1
 $ fitted.values: num [1:5] 0.636 1.273 1.909 2.545 3.182
 $ assign       : NULL
 $ qr           :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:5, 1] -7.416 0.27 0.405 0.539 0.674
  ..$ qraux: num 1.13
  ..$ pivot: int 1
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  ..$ rank : int 1
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ df.residual  : int 4
```

I'm expecting intercept = 6 and slope = -1 but the result above doesn't contain anyhing near that. Also, does lm.fit() output r squared?

Comment: What in the world are `m` and `k` supposed to be? Are you talking about the slope and intercept term? If you are passing a single column matrix to `lm.fit` you're not fitting an intercept term. Try `lm.fit(cbind(1, x), y)`.

Comment: Yea, sorry for not clarifying that, I edited the question, allright, that change did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Is there also a way of getting r squared?

Comment: From the help for lm.fit: "These are the basic computing engines called by lm used to fit linear models. These should usually not be used directly unless by experienced users."  Try using `lm(y~x)` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lm.fit` allows to do things much more manually, so, as @MrFlick commented, we must include the intercept manually as well using `cbind(1, x)` as the design matrix. The R^2 is not provided but we may easily compute it:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 5:1 + rnorm(5)
regr <- lm.fit(cbind(1, x), y)
regr$coef
#                     x 
#  5.2044349 -0.5535963 
1 - var(regr$residuals) / var(y) # R^2
# [1] 0.3557227
1 - var(regr$residuals) / var(y) * (length(y) - 1) / regr$df.residual # Adj. R^2
# [1] 0.1409636
```